# Save at the same time an composed object using JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, logic

Can I save an object that contains another object directly in the database?

My back-end structure is like this:

1. Rest services
2. Services
3. Repository (extends `JpaRepository`)
4. Model

Suppose that I have two entity in my model: `Company` and `Address`. Both generated by the JPA tool provided by IntelliJ.

**Company class model**

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    private int idcompany;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idcompany")
    public int getIdcompany() {
        return idcompany;
    }

    public void setIdcompany(int idcompany) {
        this.idcompany = idcompany;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idaddress", referencedColumnName = "idaddress", nullable = false)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**Address class model**

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    private long idaddress;
    private String zip;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idaddress")
    public long getIdaddress() {
        return idaddress;
    }

    public void setIdaddress(long idaddress) {
        this.idaddress = idaddress;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "zip")
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Moreover, both entities have an interface that extends the interface `JpaRepository<T,ID>`. So, I have `CompanyRepository` and `AddressRepository`. I use these two interfaces in they respective *Service* classes: `CompanyService` and `AddressService`. This is where I put the business logic. All **ok**!

Now, I recive using a REST service, through *POST* an object `Company` that contains the object `Address`. I need to save them into the database (MySql).

In the json file there are `Company` that contains `Address`!

Until now, I've always done these steps:

1. Save `Address`;
2. Retrieve the `Address` just saved (i need the `idaddress`);
3. I associate the `Address` to the company using `setAddress`;
4. Save `Company`

I tried to save the object `Company` received via REST calling the method `save` from `CompanyService` (using `CompanyRepository`) but I got the error:

```
Column 'idaddress' cannot be null
```

I ask you. Is there an easier way to save `Company` and `Address` *at the same time* using `JpaRepository`???

Comment: How does the json object look like that you get?

Comment: From the POST. I map the RequestBody to my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have defined any cascading.

You could define PERSIST to let the Address persist when Company is persisted:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idaddress", referencedColumnName = "idaddress", nullable = false,
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
```

For every method on the EntityManager there is a CascadeType defined.

Read more about the cascade types here:
https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/